# XMLHttpRequest "progress" event is never fired on chrome/firefox/opera

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, meteor, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to monitor the progress of my files upload, but the "progress" event is never fired on chrome, firefox and opera. It works perfectly on Safari however.

I use the package [meteor-slingshot](https://github.com/CulturalMe/meteor-slingshot) to manipulate my files. Here is the code that the package use in order to send the files :

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (event) {
  if (event.lengthComputable) {
    loaded.set(event.loaded);
    total.set(event.total);
  }
}, false);

xhr.open("POST", self.instructions.upload, true);

_.each(self.instructions.headers, function (value, key) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader(key, value);
});

xhr.send(buildFormData());
```

Do you have an idea of what is the problem? Is the problem coming directly from those browsers ?